# funcion JS debe ejecutarse despues de culmine un recorrido de un foreach en Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, funciones

En mi codigo se ejecuta la grabacion de registros
tengo mi codigo :

```
 $("#btn_imprimir_cargo").click(function() {
        var lc_cargo_id = $("#nro_reimprimir_cargo").val();
        $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
            var lc_leer_compuesto = $(this).val(),
                lc_expediente = lc_leer_compuesto.substring(0, 11),
                lc_numero = lc_leer_compuesto.substring(12);
            grabar_cargo_expediente(lc_expediente, lc_cargo_id, lc_numero);
        });

        mostrar_derivados();
        $("#btn_imprimir_cargo").attr("disabled", true);
        $('#generar_cargo').modal('toggle');
        window.open(url + 'imprimir/cargo_derivado?cargo=' + lc_cargo_id);

    });
```

el problema es que la funcion : mostrar_derivado() se ejecuta en paralelo a la grabacion, que podria hacer para que la funcion se ejecute despues de la grabacion del bucle anterior del each??jsva

Comment: Prueba con promesas, [info aquí](https://cursos.mejorcodigo.net/article/promesas-en-jquery-40) o con `async` y `await`, [en este enlace](https://petetasker.com/using-async-await-jquerys-ajax) encuentras información resumida y clara de como usarlas.

Comment: La función `grabar_cargo_expediente()` realiza tareas en async? Puedes editar el post y añadir el código de esa función?

Answer (score 1):

Un adopción es ejecutar la función mostrar_derivados() que se ejecutara en paralelo dentro de la función de grabar_cargo_expediente()

```
$("#btn_imprimir_cargo").click(function() {
  var lc_cargo_id = $("#nro_reimprimir_cargo").val();

  // saber el numero de input checked que hay
  var i = 1
  $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
    i++;
  })

  $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function( index ) {
    var lc_leer_compuesto = $(this).val(),
        lc_expediente = lc_leer_compuesto.substring(0, 11),
        lc_numero = lc_leer_compuesto.substring(12);

    // verificar cual es el ultimo elemento y ejecutar después de cargo, el mostrar_derivados()
    if( i == index ) {
      grabar_cargo_expediente(lc_expediente, lc_cargo_id, lc_numero);
      mostrar_derivados();
    } else {
      grabar_cargo_expediente(lc_expediente, lc_cargo_id, lc_numero);
    }

  });

  $("#btn_imprimir_cargo").attr("disabled", true);
  $('#generar_cargo').modal('toggle');
  window.open(url + 'imprimir/cargo_derivado?cargo=' + lc_cargo_id);

})
```